# Not able to copy multi line curl command in shell prompt

Tags: linux, shell, curl, elasticsearch

Am trying to run multiline curl command in shell but not able to run it

```
curl -XPUT 'elk.***.com:9200/_snapshot/my_backup' \
        { 
            "type": "fs", 
            "settings": { 
            "location": "/elkprod_bak/elkback", 
            "compress": true 
                } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`-d` switch](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) on the command line like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'elk.***.com:9200/_snapshot/my_backup' -d '{ 
        "type": "fs", 
        "settings": { 
          "location": "/elkprod_bak/elkback", 
          "compress": true 
        } 
}'
```